# Complex Analysis Triangular Inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I recently started learning Complex Analysis and as of now don't have much command over it, I am stuck up with this assignment Question of mine which is as follows:

If $|Z_i| < 1$ and $V_i ≥  0$ for $i = 1,2,3,\dots$ and $V_1+V_2+V_3+\cdots+V_n = 1$ then show that

$$|V_1Z_1 + V_2Z_2 + V_3Z_3+\cdots+ V_4Z_4 | < 1$$

I am quite sure that this question is an application of ***Triangle Inequality***.

Comment: I don't think the triangle inequality will help.  Could this be an application of Cauchy-Schwartz?

Comment: Yes, the triangle inequality helps you here. If you apply it, what do you get?

Comment: |V1*Z1 + V2*Z2 + V3*Z3 + .......+ Vn*Zn|  ≤  |V1*Z1| + |V2*Z2|..... + |Vn*Zn|

Comment: Okay, and now look at $\lvert V_k\cdot Z_k\rvert$. What can you say about that?

Comment: |Vk.Zk| = Vk|Zk| and |Zk| < 1 but Vk > or = 0  so we can't say anything about the Vk|Zk| but essentially the summation of all Vk's providing 1 will work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, apply the triangle inequality to get
$$|V_1Z_i+\cdots V_nZ_n| \le |V_1Z_1|+\cdots + | V_nZ_n| = V_1|Z_1|+\cdots + V_n |Z_n|.$$
The equality follows from the fact that $V_i$ is real and nonnegative. Now take the largest $|Z_i|$, say $|Z_m|$, now what can you say about this sum?

### Solution:

> $$V_1|Z_1|+\cdots +V_n|Z_n| \le V_1|Z_m|+\cdots+V_n|Z_m| = (V_1+\cdots+V_n)|Z_m|=|Z_m|<1.$$